# Simplifying nested if statements in Python

Tags: python, json, database, if-statement, simplify

I am working on a JSON database that stores multiple choice questions. I defined a function that takes some arguments that are NOT obligatory in order to fetch questions based on your needs (difficulty, subject, keyword...) and so I feel the need to use many if-else statements.

The following (**symbolic**) code works fine, but it is hard to digest.

```
def getq(mine, subject, difficulty, keyword):
    with open("questions.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for id in data.keys():
        if mine == True:
            if subject == True:
                if difficulty == True:
                    if keyword == True:
                        ...
                    else:
                        ...
                else:
                    if keyword == True:
                        ...
                    else:
                        ...
            else:
                if difficulty == True:
                    if keyword == True:
                        ...
                    else:
                        ...
                else:
                    if keyword == True:
                        ...
                    else:
                        ...
        elif subject == True:
            if difficulty == True:
                if keyword == True:
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
            else:
                if keyword == True:
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
        else:
            if difficulty == True:
                if keyword == True:
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
            else:
                if keyword == True:
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
```

It uses the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "1": {
        "question": "What's the capital of Spain?",
        "subject": "",
        "date" : "",
        "timesright" : 2,
        "timeswrong" : 3,
        "difficulty": "",  # This would be a function of timesright and timeswrong
        "keywords" : "geography, general knowledge",
        "explanation": "",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Paris",
                "is_correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Madrid",
                "is_correct": true
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "answer": "Roma",
                "is_correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "answer": "Moscow",
                "is_correct": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How could I make it easier to look at and/or more efficient? Maybe numpy?
I would highly appreciate other suggestions. Perhaps using JSON isn't the best idea given that I intend on editing it via commands? *I am a newbie, so I do not have a clue.*

Comment: Have you considered storing your json as a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) dataframe? It makes filtering easy and could lighten your code.

Comment: You can define every `...` block as a separate function, and store functions_map (or whatever) like `{(True, True, True): func1, (True, True, False): func2}` and so on. Then you can call it like `functions_map[(subject, difficulty, keyword)](*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Also if you are using python3.10+ you can use match case construction

Comment: Hard to say without more context, but querying a true SQL database like SQLite (interfaced in the Python standard library) could be easier.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have added the structure of my JSON file, would you still recommend using SQLite?

Comment: @Tranbi I expect my database to grow in size to MB levels, would you say pandas is the way to go?

Comment: pandas can definitely handle this kind of size. However, given the limited information you provided, there might be easier/more efficient ways (consider sudden_appearance solution as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments - The simplest approach is to store the json as a pandas dataframe.

Consider the following json object as a sample:

```
{
    "1": {
        "question": "some question?",
        "choices": [1,2,3,4],
        "answer": 0,
        "subject": "science",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "mine": "foobar"
    },
    "2": {
        "question": "some question?",
        "choices": [1,2,3,4],
        "answer": 0,
        "subject": "math",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "mine": "foobar"
    },
    "3": {
        "question": "some question?",
        "choices": [1,2,3,4],
        "answer": 0,
        "subject": "math",
        "difficulty": "medium",
        "mine": "foobar"
    }
}
```

Assuming this is read as `json_str`, function `getq` will look something like:

```
def getq(mine='', subject='', difficulty='', keyword=''):
    df = pd.read_json(json_str, orient='index').reset_index()

    df = df[df['mine'].str.contains(mine)]
    df = df[df['subject'].str.contains(subject)]
    df = df[df['difficulty'].str.contains(difficulty)]
    df['keyword_check'] = df.apply(lambda x: keyword in x['question'].split(' '), axis=1)
    return df[df['keyword_check']]
```

If your json data is complex, has varying schema, and is very large you might be better off using mongodb and it's querying engine

some details of your json structure (a sample perhaps) will be helpful

**EDIT:**

Your JSON structure looks fairly straightforward, I would recommend you use the pandas approach.
Further - For parsing JSON objects into python understandable objects I would recommend using `dataclasses` or `pydantic`. These allow you to interact with nested data in a more pythonic fashion. Adding an example (partial) below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import json


json_str = '''{
    "1": {
        "question": "What's the capital of Spain?",
        "subject": "",
        "date" : "",
        "timesright" : 2,
        "timeswrong" : 3,
        "difficulty": "",
        "keywords" : "geography, general knowledge",
        "explanation": "",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Paris",
                "is_correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Madrid",
                "is_correct": true
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "answer": "Roma",
                "is_correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "answer": "Moscow",
                "is_correct": false
            }
        ]
    }
}'''


@dataclass
class Answer:
    id: int
    answer: str
    is_correct: bool


@dataclass
class Question:
    question: str
    subject: str
    date: str
    timesright: int
    timeswrong: int
    difficulty: str
    keywords: str
    explanation: str
    answers: List[Answer]


for question_id, question_dict in json.loads(json_str).items():
    question = Question(**question_dict)
    if question.difficulty == "high":
        print("found a difficult one!")
```

Comment: Hello sud, thank you for such an interesting answer! I have just added a snippet of my json file as you suggested. I have never dealt with pandas before - please, keep enlightening me! I will start reading its documentation.